# jQuery Hover Menu

Tags: jquery

The following code displays a sub-menu when you hover over a menu item. Since its using a timer, if you don't select the sub-menu item fast enough, the sub-menu items disappear.  I would rather have it highlite the menu option it is on and keep the sub-menu items until you hover over or click another main menu item:

$(document).ready(function(){
    Nifty("#menu a","small top transparent");
    Nifty("#outcontent","medium bottom transparent");

```
function hideSubMenu() {
    $("#sub-menu-content").fadeOut('slow');
    hideSubMenu.timeout = 0;
}

$('#menu a').hover(function() { //start function when any link is clicked
    if (hideSubMenu.timeout) clearTimeout(hideSubMenu.timeout);
    hideSubMenu.timeout = 0;
    $("#sub-menu-content").hide();

    var html = '<ul>' + $(this).next('ul.sub-menu').html() + '</ul>&nbsp;';
    $("#sub-menu-content").html(html); //show the html inside .content div
    $("#sub-menu-content").fadeIn('fast'); //animation
},function(){
    hideSubMenu.timeout = setTimeout(hideSubMenu, 800);
}); //close click(

$('#sub-menu-content').hover(function() {
    if (hideSubMenu.timeout) clearTimeout(hideSubMenu.timeout);
    hideSubMenu.timeout = 0;
},function(){
    hideSubMenu.timeout = setTimeout(hideSubMenu, 800);
}); //close click(
}); //close $(
```

To see it in action:

http://cruisecontrolledmarketing.com/test/welcome/login
user: member password: rebmem

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Rather than hacking something up yourself, how about checking out the [hoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)?

Comment: I'll check it out.  I've never seen that before.

Comment: I recommend it. We use it in production on sites all the time. Nice and easy to configure, and should do exactly what you need it to.

Comment: I'm trying to get it to work.. would i just replace the hover events? i.e. $('#menu a').hover(function() { would become 
$("#menu a").hoverIntent( config, function() ) {

I also found jquery.event.hover-1.0.js - its supposed to be "better" than hoverIntent.  I'm checking both out.

Comment: Yeah, you'd replace .hover() with .hoverIntent(). I've found that looking at the source of their examples points you in the right direction better than their documentation. I haven't checked out jquery.event.hover, but, if you do, let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

I found an amazing page that nearly contains any kind of different concept of menus, popups, hover, and so worth with any kind of effects you can imagine. I found it incredible useful to extend some of them and make even better menus.

[45 beautiful jQuery Menu plugins and tutorials](http://www.freshdesignweb.com/jquery-menu.html)